# plotting "log relative hazard" against continuous covariate: what are knots when using cph

Tags: r, survival, cox-model

I try to get into in Cox Regression and read the example chapter from [Steyerberg's book](http://www.clinicalpredictionmodels.org/).

Afterwards I tried to plot log relative hazards against continuous variables using the rms package:

```
d  <- read.spss('~/R-Test/SMARTst.sav',use.value.labels=F, to.data.frame=T)
dd <- datadist(d)
options(datadist="dd")
fit <- cph(Surv(TEVENT,EVENT) ~  rcs(IMT,4), data=d)
plot(Predict(fit), lty=2, lwd=2)
```

What are knots? Well, I see what happens when I Change 4 to 3 or numbers > 4 ... but I do not know what I do and why? ;-) Maybe that will be explained in earlier chapters I currrently do not have.

Can someone explain it too me or recommand free websites/articles explaining this in an easy fashin (i am not a statistician).

My final goal is to learn how to create adequate cox models for exploratory medical analyses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knots are join points for piecewise cubic polynomials.  You are using 4 knots placed at default locations based on quantiles of `IMT`.  `rcs` means *restricted cubic spline* which is also called "natural spline" and has linearity restrictions beyond the outer knots.  You can see the form of the fitted function by typing `Function(fit)`, or, if you have $\LaTeX$, `latex(fit)`.  Typing `specs(fit)` will show you the actual knot locations used.  See my course handouts at http://biostat.mc.vanderbilt.edu/CourseBios330 for much more about restricted cubic splines and the `rms` package.

As an aside, the `spss.get` function in the `Hmisc` package enhances `read.spss` for better use of data frames when using `Hmisc` and `rms`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! It is quite difficult to understand what happpens as a non-mathematician. However, maybe this should not my Goal but rather how to use this. Off Topic: You wrote on your book's website that the projected publication of the second edition will be December 2014. May I ask whether this is still up to data or will it be later?

Comment: I updated that to April 2015.